# Make reference Map work on two tables on two modules

Tags: zend-framework

Hi I have two Modules on each modules i have models with table class, I want to referenceMap two table class one in each module.

This is what I have:

This one is in Invoice Module.

```
class Invoice_Resource_InvoiceByProgress extends SA_Model_Resource_Db_Table_Abstract 
      implements   Invoice_Resource_InvoiceByProgress_Interface 
{
  protected $_name = 'invoice_by_progress';
  protected $_primary = array('invoice_by_progressId');
  protected $_rowClass = 'Invoice_Resource_InvoiceByProgress_Item';

  protected $_referenceMap = array(

    'Project2client' => array(
        'columns'       => 'project2clientId',
        'refTableClass' => 'Siteanalysis_Resource_Project2client',
        'refColumns'    => 'project2clientId',
        'onDelete'      => self::CASCADE
    ),    
  );
```

And this one is in Siteanalysis Module.

```
  class Siteanalysis_Resource_Project2client extends SA_Model_Resource_Db_Table_Abstract 
         implements Siteanalysis_Resource_Project2client_Interface 
  {
      protected $_name = 'project2client';
      protected $_primary = 'project2clientId';
      protected $_rowClass = 'Siteanalysis_Resource_Project2client_Item';

      protected $_dependentTables = array('Invoice_Resource_InvoiceByProgress');

      protected $_referenceMap = array(

      'Project' => array(
        'columns'       => 'projectId',
        'refTableClass' => 'Siteanalysis_Resource_Project',
        'refColumns'    => 'projectId',
        'onDelete'      => self::CASCADE
       ),);
```

My question is how can i make $_referenceMap to work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry I think make a mistake, I just find out that you call it normally as if they were on the same module.

Comment: Then please post your answer to help others and accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that

protected $_dependentTables = array('Invoice_Resource_InvoiceByProgress');

has to be

protected $_dependentTables = array('Invoice_Resource_Invoicebyprogress');

instead of the class name the file name.